# Analysis of Alzheimer data

Tags: modeling, medicine

I have two data sets with values from Alzheimer's and healthy patients. My task is to find a decision rule for evaluating the patients. The task in the original wording:

"Think of a decision rule to differentiate between healthy and Alzheimer patients. Give a decision rule that the sum of the percentages of correctly classified persons in each group is maximal. Give another one which maximizes the total number of correct classifications."

Data:

Alzheimer:
1.70 1.95 2.04 2.24 2.27 2.28 2.35 2.56 2.57 2.77 3.93 4.21 4.69
4.72 4.74 4.75 4.92 4.95 5.37

Healthy:
1.87 1.92 1.97 1.99 2.02 2.03 2.11 2.11 2.12 2.14 2.17 2.20 2.30
2.30 2.31 2.32 2.36 2.36 2.80 2.16 2.20 2.27 2.28 2.29 2.36 2.37
2.43 2.49 2.51 2.53 2.53 2.53 2.55 2.63 2.71 2.73 2.86 2.94

The approach of the first rule should be n_classified/n_sample and maximize the sum.

The approach of the second rule should be (true positive + true negative)/ total samples.

Unfortunately, both variants have the same value of 2.94. From the task, I guess this should not be the case.

I would be grateful for any help.

```py
best_threshold = None
max_result = float('-inf')

alzheimer = [1.70, 1.95, 2.04, 2.24, 2.27, 2.28, 2.35, 2.56, 2.57, 2.77, 3.93, 4.21, 4.69, 4.72, 4.74, 4.75, 4.92, 4.95, 5.37]
healthy = [1.87, 1.92, 1.97, 1.99, 2.02, 2.03, 2.11, 2.11, 2.12, 2.14, 2.17, 2.20, 2.30, 2.30, 2.31, 2.32, 2.36, 2.36, 2.80, 2.16, 2.20, 2.27, 2.28, 2.29, 2.36, 2.37, 2.43, 2.49, 2.51, 2.53, 2.53, 2.53, 2.55, 2.63, 2.71, 2.73, 2.86, 2.94]

for threshold in np.arange(2.02, 3.5, 0.02):
    true_positive = np.sum(np.array(alzheimer) > threshold)
    true_negative = np.sum(np.array(healthy) <= threshold)


    accuracy = (true_positive + true_negative) / (len(alzheimer) + len(healthy))
    sensitivity_alzheimer = (true_positive) / len(alzheimer)
    specificity_healthy = (true_negative) / len(healthy)

    sum_of_percentages = sensitivity_alzheimer + specificity_healthy

    if accuracy > max_result:
        max_result = accuracy
        best_threshold = threshold


    print("Threshold:", threshold)
    print("True Positive (TP):", true_positive)
    print("True Negative (TN):", true_negative)

    print("Alzheimer:", sensitivity_alzheimer)
    print("Healthy:", specificity_healthy)
    print("Result Sum of Percentages:", sum_of_percentages)
    print("Result (Accuracy):", accuracy)
    print()

print("Best Threshold:", best_threshold)
print("Maximized Result (Accuracy):", max_result)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps a histogram of your data gives some better insight.
[image]

Comment: As explained [here](https://fharrell.com/post/classification) the use of forced-choice classification in this setting is highly inappropriate, as opposed to modeling tendencies.  When the predicted probability of having Alzheimer’s is near 0.5 you should not be making a decision about group membership.  Also the problem statement seems to be devoid of clinical meaning.